# Two Charts Compatible with an Atlas

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I attempt to understand the proof of the following lemma from *An Introduction to Manifolds* by Loring Tu (Second Edition, page no. 51).

**Lemma 5.8.** *Let $\lbrace (U_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha}) \rbrace$ be an atlas on a locally Euclidean space. If two charts $(V, \psi)$ and $(W, \sigma)$ are both compatible with the atlas $\lbrace (U_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha}) \rbrace$, then they are compatible with each other.*

[image]

**My Question:** 
I understand that $\sigma \circ \psi^{-1}$ is $C^{\infty}$ on $\psi(V \cap W \cap U_{\alpha})$. But I don't understand how $p$ being an arbitrary point of $V \cap W$ implies that $\sigma \circ \psi^{-1}$ is $C^{\infty}$ on $\psi(V \cap W)$ on the second last line.

An explanation would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But, Tu has shown for an arbitrary $p\in V\cap W$, that $\sigma\circ\psi^{-1}$ is smooth at $\psi(p)$.  Clearly the claim follows.  Remember, for each $p$ there's a $U_\alpha$.  So, $\psi(V\cap 
 W)=\bigcup_{p\in U\cap V}\psi(V\cap W\cap U_\alpha)$.  Now if a function is smooth on a family of open sets, it's smooth on their union.

Comment: How do we get this equation: $\psi(V\cap 
 W)=\bigcup_{p\in U\cap V}\psi(V\cap W\cap U_\alpha)$?

Comment: $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism, so it takes open sets to open sets.  But $V\cap W=\bigcup_\alpha V\cap W\cap U_\alpha$.